# Ex 1-8 The C Programming Language

Tags: c

I recently bought The C Programming Language and tried Ex 1-8
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {
    int nl,nt,nb;
    int c;
    printf("\nHello and Welcome :D\nThis is the 'answer' to Ex 1-8 in TCPG\nRemember,to end input,type in %d\n[Press <ENTER> to continue]\n",EOF);
    getch();
    for(nl = 0,nb = 0,nt = 0;(c = getchar()) != EOF; ) // When getchar is replaced by getche() it goes into the loop but doesnt exit the loop
    {
        putchar(c);
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            nl++;                        
        }
        else if(c == '\t')
        {
            nt++;
        }
        else if(c == ' ')
        {
            nb++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nYou typed in %d blanks, %d tabs and wrote %d lines\n[Press <ENTER> to exit]",nb,nt,nl);
    getch();



    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It just doesn't enter the loop!
When getchar() is replaced with getche(),it enters the loop but doesn't exit :(
if you didnt guess, putchar(c); is just to confirm the fact that it has entered the loop 
I tried Ctrl + D and Ctrl + Z
I'm using Windows 8 
Thanks guys :)

EDIT : I first used a switch case structure but thought I should go according to the book I just saw it says RUN FAILED (exit value -1, total time: 5s)  after i type a bit...
Any ideas? 
Thanks guys :) (Again :D )

Comment: You actually spent money for the book? If it contains the exact code you posted here, you should see if it can be returned. Are you sure you typed it *just like the book says*?

Comment: The only reason it doesn't enter the loop is that obviously  it read an end-of-file. Check your input which you're giving. Post the input enetered here with the newline `\n`

Comment: @KenWhite This is the answer code which OP wrote, although the book  (I verified he's referring to K&R; it is reliable for what it is) is completely outdated, and OP appears to have added even more anachronisms.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, I know. The book appears to be from the early '80s, and if that's what it's teaching it should be returned if possible in favor of a book that's at least two decades newer.

Comment: Well,I was reading on forums and almost eveyone called it the "C Bible"
Anyways,could you please point out where my code is wrong?
@UchiaItachi : I usually press enter first and then start randomly typing for some time :)

Comment: @AnitejBanerjee If by "bible" you mean "really old book", then yes. If you mean "authoritative reference", then no.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Same as a bible. It has had its day.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not be using  or getch/getche, those are not standard C. Your issue when you are using getche in the loop is that this function on MS Windows does not process end-of-file controls.

In general, the first getchar() call will not return until after you've pressed enter for the first line, so if you're expecting it to "enter the loop" immediately, you're mistaken. Just keep typing and hit enter.

Comment: "First" implies there's a second. "getch/getche" are far from the only problems (`int c` for a `char`, variables declared using `int nt,nl,nb;` that are then redeclared as loop control vars in the `for`, and using `int main()` just to mention a few). If you're using a 1980s book, `getch/getche` were typical. (And the poster said in a comment "I usually press enter first and then start randomly typing for some time".)

Comment: "redeclared as loop control vars in the for," - No, they're not, they're just initialized. There's no declaration there (though it's still odd to initialize there).  " If you're using a 1980s book, getch/getche were typical." - not K&R, since it's not a DOS book.  "I usually press enter first and then start randomly typing for some time" - yeah, he's pressing enter once for his "press enter to begin" thing, and then probably not pressing it again.

Comment: I don't remember it that way (although it's been a long time). I recall the `for(int...)` redeclaring a local variable within the scope of the loop because of the `int` being included (but it has been a couple of decades since, so I could be remembering wrong). `getch/getche` were part of most C RTLs, including those from Borland and Microsoft (and the amazing for the time $20 Mix Software PowerC compiler).

Comment: " I recall the for(int...) redeclaring a local variable within the scope of the loop because of the int being included (but it has been a couple of decades since, so I could be remembering wrong). " - Yes, this is correct. Read the code again, "int" does not appear. And, by "most C RTLs" you mean DOS ones. The C Programming Language is a Unix book, to whatever extent it can be considered to be based on a specific OS at all.

Comment: Yep. A re-read says you're right. :-) And yes, I mean DOS ones (Borland/MS/PowerC). Back then, I only had a vague idea what Unix was. :-) Glad I only commented and didn't downvote; if I had done both, I'd be scrambling now trying to figure out how to fix it. :D

Comment: So you say I should remove getch()?
Just a quick question,does getchar() also stop a program the way getch() does?
thanks :)

Comment: @AnitejBanerjee In general, you shouldn't rely on getch, because it's not a standard function. What getchar() normally does is, the first time it stops the program until you hit enter, then each subsequent call will return a character immediately until it reaches the end of the line.